# put() doesn't "put" my changes!

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm tinkering with app engine and I've written an edit form to edit my stored objects, let's say they're the model Foo.

I have this code which is all executed and doesn't produce any exceptions yet the items in the data store remain unchanged:

```
class EditFooItemHandler(BaseHandler):
    page = "edit_fooitem"
    def post(self, foo_id=None):#POST
        if not foo_id is None:
            foo_id = int(foo_id)
            new_barid = int(self.request.POST['barid'])
            item = FooItem.get_by_id(int(foo_id))
            item.barid = new_barid
            logging.info( 'Saving FooItem with id=' + str(foo_id) + 'and barid=' + str(new_barid))
            item.put()

        self.prepare()
        self.values['item'] = item
        self.finish()

    def get(self, foo_id):#GET
        self.prepare()
        logging.info( 'getreq')
        logging.info( foo_id)
        item = FooItem.get_by_id(int(foo_id))
        self.values['item'] = item
        self.finish()
```

Any ideas why `item.put()` doesn't change my data store? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you see `Saving FooItem with id=....` in your log?

Comment: Are you sure that `barid` is declared as a property inside the FooItem model class?

Comment: Yes but when I do logging.info( 'Saving FooItem with id=' + str(foo_id) + 'and barid=' + str(new_barid) +' old bar id=' + str(item.barid)) and move this line one line up I get something like 'Saving FooItem with id=12 and bar id=10 old barid=<bound method FooItem.adid of <models.FooItem object at 0x5997c10>>'. Oh noes! Thank you, I think I know why it doesn't work now!

Comment: glad I helped you in some way :)

Comment: style nitpick: `foo is not None` is preferred over `not foo is None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
barid
```

is not defined as a property but rather as a method in the model. To make the above code work I can retrieve `Bar.get_by_id(barid)` and then do

```
new_bar = Bar.get_by_id(barid)
foo.bar = new_bar
```